# Variables not showing values in <p:dialog> window

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a program that is felling some fields of an object and this object values need to appear in a modal dialog window.

When debugging the program I see the objects being filled correctly, all the values are there.

Right after feeling this values I am showing the dialog window from my bean but the values does not appear.

This is how I am defining my dialog window.

```
 <p:dialog id="infoDialogReset"
          class="dialogWindowGenericMessage"
          showHeader="false"
          widgetVar="infoDialogResetResolve" modal="true" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" resizable="false" appendTo="@(body)" closable="false">

        <p:panel id="infoDialogResetPanel" class="dialogText18Blue" header="RESET + RESOLVE CHANNEL" style="">

            <p:outputLabel >reset status ->#{channelManagement.selectedChannel.resetStatus}</p:outputLabel>

            </f:facet>
        </p:panel>
</p:dialog>
```

This is the piece of code where I am passing the values to the variables values.

```
this.selectedChannel.setResetStatus(0);

RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update(":j_idt3:mainForm:infoDialogReset");
context.execute("PF('infoDialogResetResolve').show();");
```

As the result the dialog windows is being shown as expected but the value for the channelManagement.selectedChannel.resetStatus object is not appearing.

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I doubt the clientid you update is correct since you appendTo="@(body)"

Comment: @ViewScoped Bean ?

Comment: Hi Jaquen,

I agree that this may be the issue, but if I remove the @(body) from the dialog, it opens "grayed" and not clickable.

Than I tried to use the parent ID but not working also.

Comment: Hi Michal,

Correct this is a ViewScoped bean. Do you see this as a possible issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed my approach.

Instead of calling my modal dialog screen from by back bean I have called directly from the .xhtml page.

Just for reference if someone is facing the same issue. This is the way that I am doing the call.

```
<p:commandButton ajax="true" class="buttonCommmandBlue" value="RESET" oncomplete="PF('dialogResetResolve').show()" update=":j_idt3:mainForm:panelResetResolve" action="#{channelManagement.resetChannel(channelManagement.selectedChannel.name)}">
```